# JSP FileReader URL Issue

Tags: java, jsp, url

I get the strangest thing going on...
I have a JSP file which read a file from given path, but somehow the http:// is changed to http:\

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("http://server/path/file.sql"));
```

the exception i get is:
(the file exist for sure!!! works when url is entered in webrowser).

```
exception=http:\server\path\file.sql (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://....").openStream(), "UTF-8")`

`FileReader` is used to read the filesystem, not URLs. Also have in mind that writing java code in JSP is usually not a good idea. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)

Comment: any idea why is that happaning?

Comment: which one? Your code fails because FileReader can't read URLs